# How to get each entity and store in hashmap in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, split, hashmap, modi

I am doing project on this split the data. I shown my code below, then attached output also. I am doing in Asp.net.

```
Receipt No : VH4O-RCTN093246 Receipt Date : 01/01/2015
Fathers Name : sachin tendulkar Motherâ€™s Name : NITHYA
Name of the Student : ARLJN RIKIN RUPAK
Board/Grade/Dvision : ICSE / Grade II / D App/Enr No : VH4O-ENRN04426
```

From, above want to bring this output and that should store in the HashMap(key, Value format).

```
***Output:***
 Receipt No : VH4O-RCTN093246
 Receipt Date : 01/01/2015
 Receipt No : VH4O-RCTN093246
 Board : ICSE 
 Grade: Grade II 
 Dvision : D 
 App/Enr No : VH4O-ENRN04426
```

code:

```
int length = split_text.Length;

do
{
    string tmp;
    tmp = split_text[i]; // Contain input text

    if (tmp.Contains("Receipt No "))
    {
        string[] words;
        words = tmp.Split(':');

        string[] wor = words[1].Split(' ');
        rep_name1 = wor[1];
    }

    if (tmp.Contains("Name of the Student "))
    {
        string[] words;
        words = tmp.Split(':');

        s_name1 = words[1];
    }
    if (tmp.Contains("Grade"))
    {
        string[] words;
        words = tmp.Split('/');

        string[] wor = words[2].Split(':');

        board = wor[1];
        grade = words[3];
        string[] b = words[5].Split(':');

        enroll_no = b[1];// +read.ReadLine();
    }
    if (tmp.Contains("Fee "))
    {
        string[] words;
        words = tmp.Split(' ');
        fee = words[7];
    }
    length--;
    i++;
}

while (length != 0);
```

I hardcode this. Please give idea/code to gentralize this.

Comment: Is the source a class or string?

Comment: And where is the code ? And what is the key ? The Receipt No ?

Comment: This is String Only.  Key like (Receipt No , Fathers Name,Board/Grade/Dvision,App/Enr No)